# Sending a file as the body of an email

Tags: command-line, email

I want a utility that does something like this:

```
email --subject="xxx" --body=body.txt --to=to_address@hostname.com
```

(using pre-configured sender information for e.g. gmail). Note that `body.txt` is plain text and should be the body of the message, not an attachment. If the body is omitted it should pop up an editor and let me type in my message that way.

I could hack together a quick script that does this, but I was wondering if there's an easy way to do this with common unix tools?

Comment: `mutt` will do it, if you're using it as your MUA. Check the synopsis in its manpage.

Comment: My favorite is the [email](http://www.cleancode.org/projects/email) ([github](https://github.com/deanproxy/eMail)) MTA client. `cat body.txt | email -subject "unix.stackexchange.com Q71206" -from-name isbadawi -from-addr isbadawi@domain.com -smtp-server smtp.domain.com -cc isbadawi@domain.com -bcc isbadawi@domain.com isbadawi@domain.com,isbadawi2@domain.com`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The mail/mailx utilities do most of what you want. What it does not do, is open an editor on empty contents. The body of the email is read through `stdin`. Here is an example on usage:

```
mail -s "xxx" to_address@hostname.com < body.txt
```

Comment: fwiw mutt can do this from the command line as well (meaning you can script the sending of email) plus it's easier to send MIME attachments with mutt (just requires the -a option). Doesn't really change or invalidate your answer at all but it does add another possibility to the list.

Answer (score 1):

That can be done with most of the CLI mail clients, standard is `mail`/`mailx`. To do a bit more funky stuff, you could use `mimesend(1)` (here on Fedora 18 it is in the perl-MIME-tools package), it does as you say, but the body gets MIME encoded (aka attachment).