# Mailx command in UNIX

Tags: mailx

How to send body content template to DL groups using MAILX command?

Ex:- Whenever process is down,i need to send to email with body content to all the DL groups.

Comment: `man mailx` maybe?

Comment: mailx -s "DDS  Processors are not running in UAT"   XXX@.com   -- -r XXX@@l.com

Comment: I need body content with template along with email required help

Comment: `-q file   -   
    Start the message with the contents of the specified file. May be given in send mode only.` So if you put your body content into files, you can sent them with this command line option. `mailx -s "DDS Processors are not running in UAT" -q ./mails/DDS_not_running.txt XXX@.com -- -r XXX@@l.com`

Answer (score 0):

Body of mailx is read through `stdin`. Usage:

```
mail -s "xxx" to_address@hostname.com < body.txt
```

BTW the question is already [answered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71206/sending-a-file-as-the-body-of-an-email)

Comment: Instead of answering you should close the question (or flag for closing). If you have enough reputation downvoting (does not show any research effort) might be appropriate as well.